# How to declare array of same class type in header file?

Tags: c++

I am new to `c++`. I have a class called `QuadTree`. Now `QuadTree` can contain array of 4 other `QuadTree`. Either they all have values or they all will be null. So in my class header file `QuadTree.h` is as below.

```
    class QuadTree
    {
    public:
        QuadTree();
        ~QuadTree();

        void Clear();

    private:
        QuadTree nodes_[4];

    };
```

but this nodes_ declaration show error that

```
'incomplete type is not allowed'.
```

I have also tried

```
  QuadTree* nodes_[4];
```

then when I initialize in constructor

```
nodes_ = new QuadTree[4];
```

It gives me error `'expression must be a modifiable value'.`
I can declare that as list or something. but it's size is constant(always 4). So I want to use array. Please help me to declare in header file and how to initialize in constructor in `QuadTree.cpp` file.

Comment: `QuadTree nodes_[4];` does not work because the size of `QuadTree` would be infinite since every `QuadTree` will contain an array of 4 `QuadTree` each will contain an array of 4 ...

Comment: But I want to keep null for first ever instance created in constructor.

Comment: Add this line `class QuadTree;` before class declaration. I.e. `class QuadTree
; class QuadTree
    {...}`

Comment: The problem here is that you are trying to create instances of a class before it's definition is fully available, hence the "incomplete type" message.

Comment: @VictorGubin A forward declaration doesn't make the type completed either.

Comment: You should rethink your design. `QuadTree` should either be the data type and then you have a list of objects in another class or `QuadTree`is the lis, but then the data type should be another class.

Comment: So what should I do? I can't use array for this?

Comment: Correct. You cannot use an array. C++ simply does not work this way. You can use a `std::vector`, though.

Comment: This is what I am trying to achieve.
https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-use-quadtrees-to-detect-likely-collisions-in-2d-space--gamedev-374

Comment: It has class QuadTree with array of QuadTree. Can It be done in c++ in similar way?

Comment: Are you permitted to use `std::vector`? That is a simple and correct way that also avoids manual resource management (and dealing with the rule of 3 or 5).

Comment: Well I am permitted to use vector. I just read that it consumes more memory than array. so that's why I am trying to optimize with array.

Comment: What you're "trying to achieve" is a Java program, and not C++. Java is not C++, and objects and classes work fundamentally differently, in these two languages.

Comment: Okay thanks guys. I think then I will be using vector if there is no way of using array for this in c++ like java.

Comment: If you want a static array of 4 `QuadTree` objects I recommend that you create a second class that contains these.

Comment: You could fix `QuadTree* nodes_[4];` to work with `new` but then you need to deal with the rule of 3 / 5 / 0 https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three also modern c++ discourages the usage of `new`.

Comment: A Java array and a C++ array are quite different things, because of semantics of the languages.    In C++, a `std::vector`  is closer to being equivalent to a Java array than a C++ array is.   That's just the way it is.

Comment: Okay  drescherjm. Let me try that now. will it be allowed because they both class will be dependent on each other?

Comment: With the original design (and vector or new) you still have to deal with the infinite size problem. At some point a `QuadTree` should not have an array of 4 `QuadTree`

Comment: @drescherjm I tried using other class that contain array of QuadTree. but it gives same error.

Comment: It's allowed.   There are some things that may get in your way (e.g. constructing multiple `QuadTree`s in the constructor of `QuadTree` - for example, if `QuadTree`s constructor sets the size of the vector - can cause infinite recursion if the same constructor is called to initialise the array) but such things can be managed with appropriate care.

Comment: You can use a forward declaration and a reference. However why does a `QuadTree` need to know about a structure containing 4 `QuadTree`

Answer (score 3):

A class cannot contain instances of itself.  Doing so would require the class to be infinitely large, since each sub-object would contain a sub-sub-object, which would contain a sub-sub-sub-object, etc.

What a class *can* contain, is pointers to objects of its own type.  Since a pointer can be null, it's possible to stop the infinite loop and only have a finite number of objects.

That means the following will work:

```
class QuadTree
{
public:
    QuadTree() : nodes_{nullptr}
    {
    }

    ~QuadTree() { delete[] nodes_; }

    // I've deleted these to make a QuadTree non-copyable.
    // You'll need to implement them to do a deep copy if you want that
    QuadTree(const QuadTree& other) = delete;
    QuadTree& operator=(const QuadTree& other) = delete;

    void Clear();

    void split() {
        nodes_ = new QuadTree[4] {
            { /* TODO QuadTree args */ },
            { /* TODO QuadTree args */ },
            { /* TODO QuadTree args */ },
            { /* TODO QuadTree args */ }
        };
    }

private:
    QuadTree* nodes_;
};
```

A smart pointer like `std::unique_ptr` could clean up the memory management a bit:

```
class QuadTree
{
public:
    // No longer have to explicitly initialize nodes_ to nullptr
    // since a default-constructed unique_ptr is null
    QuadTree();

    // No longer need to delete[] here; unique_ptr handles that for us
    ~QuadTree();

    // Copy constructor and assignment are now implicitly deleted since
    // unique_ptr is non-copyable.
    // You'll need to implement them to do a deep copy if you want that

    void Clear();

    void split() {
        nodes_.reset(new QuadTree[4] {
            { /* TODO QuadTree args */ },
            { /* TODO QuadTree args */ },
            { /* TODO QuadTree args */ },
            { /* TODO QuadTree args */ }
        });
    }

private:
    std::unique_ptr<QuadTree[]> nodes_;
};
```

To avoid the manual memory management, you could use a `std::vector<QuadTree>` instead of a raw `QuadTree*`. This comes with a small amount of memory overhead, since each `std::vector` has to track its size, but it makes it much less likely you'll end up with memory corruption issues, so it's likely worth it.  Memory is cheap these days.

```
class QuadTree
{
public:
    QuadTree();
    ~QuadTree();

    // QuadTree is now implicitly copyable, since std::vector does a deep-copy by default

    void Clear();

    void split() {
        nodes_ = {
            { /* TODO QuadTree args */ },
            { /* TODO QuadTree args */ },
            { /* TODO QuadTree args */ },
            { /* TODO QuadTree args */ }
        };
    }

private:
    std::vector<QuadTree> nodes_;
};
```

To avoid the memory overhead of `std::vector` while keeping nice clean code, you could implement your own vector-like class with a static size.  Writing such a class is a bit beyond the scope of a SO answer though.

Comment: Note that `std::vector` is bigger than just a pointer, and that overhead will be multiplied by the number of nodes. Custom data structures are a rare case where using a custom wrapper for a dynamic array may be preferable.

Comment: Agreed - make a vector-like class with fixed bounds 

Comment: In above split method(the first type with array)

nodes_ = new Quadtree[4] {
            { /* TODO QuadTree args */ },
            { /* TODO QuadTree args */ },
            { /* TODO QuadTree args */ },
            { /* TODO QuadTree args */ }
        };

It is giving error that 'expected a type specifier'

Comment: @mevitex I typoed `QuadTree` as `Quadtree`, but beyond that, it [works for me](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/612e4cb3d5545e68).

Comment: @eerorika - A `std::vector` itself is bigger than a pointer, since it also tracks the number of elements.  But the overhead is not multiplied by the number of elements the vector contains.   For example, a vector may contain a pointer (to the first element) and a `size_t`, and that overhead doesn't grow as the number of elements increases.     Yes, the memory usage for the elements increases with the number of elements, but that's not specific to vector - it's equally true for an array - dynamically allocated or not, contained in a vector or not.

Comment: @Peter the overhead is not multiplied by the number of vector elements. The overhead is multiplied by the number of vector objects. And each node contains a vector. Therefore the overhead of the vector (compared to pointer) is multiplied by the number of nodes. Tracking the number of elements is in fact the reason for the bigger size, and that feature is unused when the size is constant.

Comment: @Peter That's true, but since each element would include a `std::vector` of its own, the overhead will add up if these structures get to be large.  I agree a vector-like class with static bounds is a good approach, but writing such a thing is a bit beyond the scope of a SO answer.  I added a mention of that at the end of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
class QuadTree
{
    QuadTree nodes_[4];
```

This is not possible because if every QuadTree contains 4 QuadTrees, and all of those QuadTrees contain 16 QuadTree children total, and all of those QuadTrees contain 256 total ... up to infinity QuadTrees. You cannot have a type of infinite size. It is also not possible because it is not possible to declare an array of incomplete type, and the class is incomplete within its definition (except the complete-class context, but that does not apply here).

A tree is a linked data structure. Therefore you should be using links i.e. pointers to connect the nodes:

```
class QuadTree
{
    QuadTree* nodes_[4];
```

---

> then when I initialize in constructor
>
> ```
> nodes_ = new QuadTree[4];
> ```

Arrays are not assignable.

And, you really shouldn't create instances of `QuadTree` within the constructor of `QuadTree` unconditionally or else you have an infinite recursion, and will overflow your stack.

A default initialised `QuadTree` should probably not have any children. In other words, the child pointers should either point to null, or the sentinel object depending on the design of your data structure. In order to initialise an array of pointers to null, you can use value-initialisation. Simplest is to use a default member initialiser:

```
class QuadTree
{
    QuadTree* nodes_[4] = {};
```

---

Alternative consideration: Using `std::unique_ptr` might be a better choice than a bare pointer.

Performance consideration: If the tree always has either 0 or 4 children, then creating all children in one array, and having a pointer to that array is preferable. See [Miles Budnek's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56426280/2079303) for more details.

Comment: Actually in constructor I just want to initialize array with null pointer.

Comment: You don't need an array of 4 `QuadTree*`.  You just need one `QuadTree*` that points to an array of 4 `QuadTree`s.

Comment: How to declare that? Can you please write syntax here?

Comment: Your book probably explains dynamically allocating arrays!

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> QuadTree* nodes_[4];
> ```

That's one option—an array of four pointers to child nodes.
Another option is

```
QuadTree *nodes_;
```

which is a pointer to array of nodes. You have to keep track of the length separately, but if it is always 4 it's clear—it only allows you to have no or exactly 4 children nodes though.

---

```
nodes_ = new QuadTree[4];
```

is initialization for the *later*. It returns a pointer to an array of four instances of `QuadTree`.

In the former case, the array is embedded in the object, so you initialize each member separately.

First, you should initialize it to contain four null pointers in the constructor. You do that like

```
QuadTree::QuadTree() : nodes_() {}
```

The initialization of arrays is a bit tricky, but `nullptr` is the default value here, so explicit initialization does what you need.

Then when you actually need the children, you simply do

```
nodes_[n] = new QuadTree();
```

You should probably have a parametric constructor that will initialize the other members so you don't start out with invalid objects.

---

However, in this day and age, what you should really be using is either

```
std::unique_ptr<QuadTree> nodes_[4];
```

an array of *smart* pointers, that will take care of deleting the child nodes when you `delete` the parent—because in C++ you must manage your memory. Or, for the second option, use

```
std::vector<QuadTree> nodes_;
```

`vector` is an array that will manage it's length—you have to make sure the QuadTree has correct *move* constructor though.

Answer (score -1):

First, yes, you can only use pointer array in this case. Otherwise, it will be an endless cycle.

Second, you don't have to call 'new' for the array, since it's been already allocated when the object was created.

so you can use it directly

```
QuadTree::QuadTree() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        nodes_[i] = 0;
    }
}
```

or

```
QuadTree::QuadTree() {
    memset(nodes_, 0, sizeof(nodes_));
}
```

Comment: The array is fixed size. Initializing it with a loop, in constructor body, is doubly an antipattern. Yes, it is correct. It is also a poor example.

Comment: @JanHudec, yes, you're right, there's better choice. I've revised the answer based on your suggestion. Thx.

Comment: No, memset is not a better choice. As far as I can tell there is nothing that would guarantee null pointers are actually represented with zeroes, though all practical compilers I've ever heard of do it that way. But they don't have to, so `memset` is actually Undefined Behaviour™. And the antipattern is sill there.

Comment: `memset` is a poor choice. `std::fill` at the very least plz for type safety

Comment: Yes, this is not good enough. Actually I prefer @eerorika's way to initialize, after I saw it:  `class QuadTree{ QuadTree* nodes_[4] = {};`